# Vagrant SSH connection failure

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and three Vagrant/VirtualBox VMs that need to be turned on at the same time

When I installed Vagrant with VirtualBox, the first day, SSH connection was going correctly. At the following day I obtained this at the three machines (Here is an example of one of them):

```
xxxx-callserver@xxxxcallserver-Precision-WorkStation-T5400:~/VM$ vagrant up vvs --provision
Bringing machine 'vvs' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> vvs: Checking if box 'dmservices/fedora17-x86_64' is up to date...
==> vvs: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> vvs: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> vvs: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    vvs: Adapter 1: nat
    vvs: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> vvs: Forwarding ports...
    vvs: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> vvs: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> vvs: Booting VM...
==> vvs: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    vvs: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    vvs: SSH username: vagrant
    vvs: SSH auth method: password
    vvs: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    vvs: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Until it triggers a Time Out

And when I try to `vagrant ssh vvs`, with or without `--plain`:

```
==> vvs: The machine you're attempting to SSH into is configured to use
==> vvs: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script entering the
==> vvs: password for you. If you're prompted for a password, please enter
==> vvs: the same password you have configured in the Vagrantfile.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This the part of the Vagrantfile for that machine (the only differences between the three machines is the name, the ip (inside the same network 192.168.33.0/24) and that the other two are debian/jessie64):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    ...
    ...
    config.vm.define "vvs" do |vvs|
        vvs.vm.hostname = "vvs"
        vvs.vm.box = "dmservices/fedora17-x86_64"
        vvs.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.4"
        vvs.ssh.username = "vagrant"
        vvs.ssh.password = "vagrant"
        vvs.vm.synced_folder "/home/xxxx-callserver/NetBeansProjects", "/NetBeansProjects", create: true, type: "virtualbox"  
        vvs.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
            v.memory = 2048
            v.cpus = 2
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "64"]
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance and ask me for more info if needed

**EDIT:** Output of vagrant ssh-config

```
Host avaya
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2201
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/xxxx-callserver/VM/.vagrant/machines/avaya/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL

Host videogateway
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2200
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/xxxx-callserver/VM/.vagrant/machines/videogateway/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL

Host vvs
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Comment: Are you able to access to that IP directly using ssh (using the same credentials? Are you able to login with those credentials through Virtualbox GUI? What is the output of `vagrant ssh-config`?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu Edited the ssh-config. And yes, I can access to the OS as if I was using just plain VirtualBox

Comment: And are you able to connect using ssh `ssh -p 2222 UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null vagrant@127.0.0.1` or `ssh -p 2200 UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/xxxx-callserver/VM/.vagrant/machines/videogateway/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Did you put 3 vagrant VM in SAME computer or 3 different computer ?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu Gives the following error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname userknownhostsfile=/dev/null: Name or service not known`

Comment: @mootmoot The 3 machines are in the same computer and in the same Vagrantfile

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you explicitly forwarding each of your Vagrant guest port 22 to different host port.  I am not familiar with vagrant script, but you really need a line to explicitly specify different port, because default Vagrant always map 22 to 2222. For multiple VM. This mean only the first vagrant VM will map it correct, the rest will failed. In Vagrantfile, you need something like this for each guest machine.

```
# avaya
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, id: 'ssh', guest:22, host: 2201, 

# videogateway
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, id: 'ssh', guest:22, host: 2200, 

# vvs
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, id: 'ssh', guest:22, host: 2222,
```

Since you already have the first VM setup the port forwarding from 22 to 2222, all the 3 VM will failed change the port forwarding map. Perhaps you should consider change host `vvs` forwarding to different host port, so it will not conflict with future adhoc vagrant startup that use the default power forwarding.

Comment: I only turned on one VM (`vvs`) with `vvs.vm.network "forwarded_port", id: "ssh", guest: 22, host: 2201` in the Vagrantfile (`videogateway` has 2202 and `avaya` has 2200) and it continues to loop into `vvs: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...` until timeout